# $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma$ in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I hope this is not too silly a question: We often see

$$\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},$$ taking $c=1$.

Problem: 
I don't understand why...

In the Minkowski metric, using the $(-+++)$ signature and taking $c=1$, 
$$ds^2=-dt^2+d\vec x^2\\
d\tau^2=-ds^2\\
\implies d\tau^2=dt^2-d\vec x^2\\
\implies 1=\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2-v^2\\
\implies \frac{dt}{d\tau}=\sqrt{1+v^2}\neq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

What has gone wrong? with my reasoning?

Comment: $v=dx/dt\neq dx/d\tau$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You made a simple error; $dx/d\tau\neq v$!.  Start from your equation
$$
 d\tau^2 = dt^2 - d\vec x^2
$$
Now, divide both sides by $dt$ *not* $d\tau$ to get
$$
  \left(\frac{d\tau}{ dt}\right)^2 = 1-v^2
$$
which gives
$$
  \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1}{\gamma}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a consequence of the Lorentz transformation law and the definition of proper time. To see this, remember that if we have a coordinate system $(t^{\prime},x^{\prime})$ which has a relative velocity $v$ with respect to a coordinate system $(t,x)$, then Lorentz transformation tells us that

$$dt=\gamma(dt^{\prime}-v dx^{\prime}) $$

Now, if we let $(t^{\prime},x^{\prime})$ to be the coordinate system moving with a worldline, we get that $x^{\prime}=0$ and $t^{\prime}=\tau$, hence we have $dt=\gamma d\tau$ (since $x^{\prime}=0$), hence $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma$